# Why does a IRFZ44N turn fully on on my battery discharger while a IRFZ46N doesn't?

Tags: mosfet, discharge

I've made a simple MCU controlled NiMH AA battery tester a while ago and it works just fine. The schematic below is its discharge circuit for one NiMH AA cell.

[image: Discharger circuit schematic]

Q3 is a [IRFZ44N](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irfz44n.pdf) MOSFET. Signals `to ADC 1` and `to ADC 2` are used by the MCU for measuring battery and MOSFET voltages, respectively, while the `from MCU` is a 5V signal that turns the MOSFET on and off to control the cell discharge through R8.

The tester discharges two cells independently (thus it has two independent instances of the above circuit).

To cut a long story short, today I replaced one of the IRFZ44N by a [IRF46N](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irfz46n.pdf) and the respective discharger circuit **stopped working**. I inspected the IRFZ46N with a DMM and verified that it doesn't turn on with the 5V MCU signal: the 1.2V from the battery shows up across source and drain.

Then I inspected the original IRFZ44N on the other discharge circuit (on the same board) and it turns on fully. Its drain to source voltage is about 15mV when on and the rest of the battery voltage is across on R8 as intended.

What I find strange is that these MOSFETs are almost identical, the Z46 being just a little beefier than the Z44 (56A max current on the former versus 49A on the latter).

I know that I'm probably using the wrong MOSFETs. They both have 2 to 4V threshold voltage (Vgs-th), so they probably fully turn on at higher than 5V (maybe 9 or 10V?). I should have picked one with 1V Vgs-th, but I'm now curious: **why does the Z44N turn fully on while the Z46N doesn't?**

Comment: IRFZ46 should turn on about like the Z44. Are you sure the Z46 is not damaged? Does it turn on with 10V Vgs?

Comment: @gsills - That's what I thought - they should turn on at about the same voltage. I have other 5 Z46's behaving the same in another board (I was building a 6-cell discharger when this happened). I'll breadboard the Z46 tomorrow and try to turn it on at 10V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have measured the battery voltage on the gate.

The datasheet for irfz46N states:

VGS(th) Gate Threshold Voltage 2.0 ––– 4.0 V VDS = VGS, ID = 250μA

1.2V would not do much on this device. You can suspect issues with the gate driving circuit.

This is the UI characteristic of IRFZ46N. Parameter is Vgs.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I measured the voltage between source and drain but made a mistake when I posted the question. I've corrected it.

Comment: Did you measure how much is Vgate-source? This must work the threshold voltages are the same. See picture above.

Comment: Tested my setup with a new batch of Z44N's and they didn't turn on either, just like the Z46N's. So I conclude that the design is marginal but unit-to-unit variations were the reason the original 44's were working. Once more I'm operating devices outside their spec and had the board working by pure luck. But it's a good learning experience as I'm forced to study MOSFETs in more detail. Also, I've redesigned the gate driving circuit to apply 12V to the gate and that is turning all the MOSFETs fully on, even with 1.2V Vgs. Thanks again for your answer.